# How do I force two arrays to hold the same horizontal space?

Tags: align, matrices, arrays

In a previous topic ([Why do horizontal matrices look different than multistory matrices?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481733/why-do-horizontal-matrices-look-different-than-multistory-matrices)), it was asked why a vector holds a different horizontal space from what a matrix holds. One solution devised is to use `bvector` environment. The matrices in the question are for state-space representation of physical systems dynamics. Thus, they are of interest to me.

When I illustrate or try to explain concepts in a clear fashion, I usually use matrices with rules to divide the matrices as follows

[image]

As you can see above, the space held by the vector is slightly larger than the one held by the matrix. Further, the space held internally (i.e., between the brackets `[` and `]`) are slightly larger with the matrix. This leads to visually distracting equations. Thus, in case that I use `array` to draw matrices, how can I force the two matrices to

1. hold the same total space
2. hold the same space between the brackets surrounding them

Also, the vector `x` in the last equation does not align with the one above it unless I add a phantom content as shown in the empty box. Can I get the two vectors to align without inserting the phantom content?

```
\documentclass[10pt,norsk, fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1.2cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\usepackage{adjustbox}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\ssarray}{
    \begin{array}{cc !{\vrule width 0.1mm}c}
        2 &1 &1
        \\
        3 &-2 &-2
        \\
        \hline
        1 &1 &2
\end{array}
                    }

\begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.2\textwidth}}
    \begin{fleqn}
        $\begin{aligned}
            \dot{\vec{x}}(t) &= \textbf{A}\vec{x}(t) + \textbf{B}\vec{u}(t)\\
            \vec{y}(t) &= \textbf{C}\vec{x}(t) + \textbf{D}\vec{u}(t)
        \end{aligned} \medspace \to \medspace$
    \end{fleqn}
\end{adjustbox}
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.6\textwidth}}
    \begin{fleqn}
        \begin{alignat*}{2}
            \dot{\textbf{x}} = &\adjustbox{cframe=green 0.1mm}{$\left[\ssarray\right]$} &\vec{x} + \left[
                \begin{array}{c}
                    2
                    \\
                    1
                    \\
                    \hline
                    2
                \end{array}
            \right] \vec{u}
         \\
            \vec{y} = &\adjustbox{cframe=green 0.1mm}{
                        $\left[
                            \begin{array}{cc !{\vrule width 0.1mm}c}
                                2 &-2 &-2
                            \end{array}
                          \right]$
                                                    }
                    &\vec{x} \adjustbox{phantom, cframe=green 0.1mm}{$\medspace +
            \left[
                \begin{array}{c}
                2
                \\
                1
                \\
                \hline
                2
                \end{array}
            \right]
            \vec{u}$}
        \end{alignat*}
    \end{fleqn}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: one way is to draw them with `matrix` library from the `tikz` package.

Comment: There is also \mathmakebox from the mathtools package.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `\mathmakebox`.

Not sure why you want all the vertical space in the second equation.

```
\documentclass[10pt,norsk, fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1.2cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\sbox0{$% measure inside width
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
        2 &1 &1
        \\
        3 &-2 &-2
        \\
        \hline
        1 &1 &2
\end{array}$}%
\sbox1{$\left[\usebox0\right]$}% measure outside width
\sbox2{$\left[\begin{array}{c}
        2\\1\\ \hline 2
    \end{array}\right]$}% measure height
$\begin{aligned}
    \vec{x}\ '(t)   &= \textbf{A}\vec{x}(t) + \textbf{B}\vec{u}(t)\\
    \vec{y}(t)      &= \textbf{C}\vec{x}(t) + \textbf{D}\vec{u}(t)
\end{aligned}\ \ \ \to\ \ \ 
\begin{aligned}
    \dot{\textbf{x}} & = \usebox1 \vec{x} + \usebox2 \vec{u}\\
    \vec{y} & = \mathmakebox[\wd1][c]{\left[
      \mathmakebox[\wd0][c]{\begin{array}{cc|c}0&-1&-1\end{array}}
      \right]} \vec{x} \raisebox{0pt}[\ht2][\dp2]{}% or \vphantom{usebox2}
\end{aligned}$
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]